# CPU does not have AES-NI, which is required

Tags: cpu-mining, vps

I have a problem. I made it with this tutorial http://fucking-it.com/articles/bitcoin/771-monero-cpu-mining-on-linux

In the last step I get this message **CPU does not have AES-NI, which is required.**

What do I do with this?

Comment: Use JCE miner. It supports non-AES CPUs

Answer (score 2):

You can't efficiently mine using a chip that doesn't support AES-NI.

Verify that the current CPU has the AES instruction set using the following command:

```
grep -m1 -o aes /proc/cpuinfo
```

If it supports AES-NI, your output will be "aes" . If it doesn't output anything, you can't mine on your Raspberry Pi using cpuminer.

Comment: I got nothing. What shloud I do now? Mining on raspberry pi?

Comment: That means u cant mine on your Pi. But pi have a GPU u can utilize that. I couldn't find any tools online. Even though if u code one script the hashrate will be terribly low as < 1 H/s

Comment: Ok, I understand

Comment: You can try using a different miner.  I got this error with [`CPUMiner-Multi`](https://github.com/hyc/cpuminer-multi), but the same computer works with [`minergate-cli`](https://minergate.com/downloads/console).

Answer (score 1):

What is the CPU in your system?

That miner is no longer supported.

Perhaps use this this: [CPUMiner-Muli](https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi)

Read the [build instructions](https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi/blob/linux/README.md#build) to build it for your *nix

Basic instructions:

```
Download the miner
$ git clone https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi

If using Ubuntu do
$ apt-get install automake autoconf pkg-config libcurl4-openssl-dev libjansson-dev libssl-dev libgmp-dev make g++

$ cd cpuminer-multi

$ ./build.sh

$ make install

See what your options with
$ cpuminer --help

Usually you would do something like
$ cpuminer -t 2 -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://whateverpool.com:0420 -u youraddresshere -p x
```

Comment: ok, thank you for your help, but I do not know what I should do. It is my first time when I do it. Can you explain me well what I should do?

Comment: I added some basic instructions but didn’t test them so comment on any corrections you discover

Comment: I did everything as you and I got this massage: cpuminer: command not found

Comment: Are you sure it built ok? Are you in the correct directory where cpuminer is? ./cpuminer —help

Comment: Yes, when I build it I got this: make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/cpuminer-multi'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/cpuminer-multi'

Comment: What are the errors (if any) before the leaving directory part? There doesn’t seem to be an issue

Comment: I have this: "ablake.o algo/cpuminer-quark.o algo/cpuminer-neoscrypt.o algo/cpuminer-nist5.o a                                     lgo/cpuminer-pluck.o algo/cpuminer-qubit.o algo/cpuminer-scrypt.o algo/cpuminer-                                     scrypt-jane.o algo/cpuminer-sha2.o algo/cpuminer-sia.o" What now?

Comment: I’m not really sure what you’re asking.. those are just things you see during compile. Have you checked to see if cpuminer exists and is executable ?

Comment: How can I check cpuminer exists and is executable?